# Android: Can i set custombase adapter to a textview

Tags: android, listview, textview

This is how i populate the data to
adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

is there any option for me to do for setting textview to a custom base adapter
like below?
textview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: no, there is such method for adding an adapter for textview..

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: you can do this with linear layout same as list view.

Comment: i m working on a add to cart type of example, the problem is when i press add to  cart button the item is added to the listview but it converting itself to scrollable it is not pushing the below items like button, other textviews down.